# ¿Como dejar de Cargar por defecto los registros de un formulario con un campo de tipo foreign key en django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

tengo un formulario de VENTAS con un campo de tipo `foreign key` de CLIENTE, y lo he convertido en un buscador ese campo en el lado del cliente, pero django por defecto lo carga todos los registros existentes de los clientes en un SELECT, y si habría por por ejemplo unos 10mil registros de CLIENTES voy a tener serios problemas en carga de datos, por ello requiero que no me traiga ningún registro de CLIENTES por defecto, simplemente tiene que activarse cuando haga búsqueda o petición vía AJAX.
¿Cómo evitar la carga de esos registros por DEFECTO, estoy trabajando con `forms.ModelForm` 
NOTA: mi buscador de CLIENTES vía AJAX ya funciona y estoy trabajando con Select2, adjunto una captura del buscador.
 [image: CAMPO CLIENTE CON TODOS LOS REGISTROS DE LA BASE DE DATOS]

Algunos detalles de form y views:

> extracto de formulario VENTAS:

```
class VentaForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Venta
    exclude = ()
    widgets = {
       .....
        'cliente': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
```

> extracto de views donde mando a renderizar el Formulario de ventas

```
    @login_required
def formventas(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ........
    else:
        formVenta = VentaForm()
    return render(request, "tienda/venta.html", {'formVenta': formVenta})
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más rápido es: si no quieres usar un campo, **no lo uses**.

Hay varias formas para lograr esto, pero creo que la más sencilla es *excluirlo* de la lista de campos de tu modelo.

```
class VentaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Venta
        exclude = ['cliente', ]
```

Lo único que tienes que hacer es asegurarte que envías el objeto cliente al método `save()`, por ejemplo, haciendo la consulta y guardando el resultado en lugar del valor del formulario:

```
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.cliente =  Cliente.objects.get(pk=request.POST['cliente'])
```

> #### Nota
>
> Gracias a Alejandro Hurtado por [comentar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66481/como-dejar-de-cargar-por-defecto-los-registros-de-un-formulario-con-un-campo-de/66489?noredirect=1#comment121497_66489) la forma correcta de guardar el objeto `Cliente`.

Comment: Muchas gracias @toledano, funciona muy bien.

Comment: solo un pequeño detalle de asignar Cliente: Cliente.objects.get(pk=request.POST['cliente']

Comment: Estimado @toledano, quizá me puedes explicar cuales serian los otros métodos para dejar de traer los datos de de un campo foreign key, mi caso es que tengo una relación OneToOneField y por ejemplo cuando excluyo y activo mi buscador a veces cuando inserto datos duplicados me arroja error, **duplicate key value violates unique constraint** y quisiera devolver ese error por Form Invalid, en este caso no me va validar ese campo  porque prácticamente no es parte de mi form, porque lo he excluido, gracias

Comment: O quizá alguna forma de generarlo Form Invalid y devolverlo al usuario? así con exclusión?